# Как вытащить данные со страницы сайта, если они передаются в js коде? Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

У меня есть задача спарсить один сайт. Проблема в том, что там используется что-то типа vue/react/angular и серверный рендеринг. Но очень странный серверный рендеринг. Данные отправляются в самом документе, но они не сгенерированы в html. Они в js коде. То есть возвращается примерно такой документ:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content"></div>

    <script>
        let data = {...}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Где data обычный js объект. Далее уже у клиента данные из переменной data преобразуются в html. Как такое парсить с помощью python?

Comment: вырезайте кусок с data и загружайте в json - даже парсить не нужно - халява

Comment: @Inventor Реализовал один из возможных вариантов решения вашей задачи, [оформил в ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1228350/267338), проверьте сработает ли для вас. Жду предложений по возможным доработкам!

Comment: @eri проблема в том, что объекты js не схожи с json. Пример js объекта: `{admin: true}`. JSON выдаст ошибку и не распарсит такое. Должно быть: `{"admin": true}`

Comment: @Inventor есть парсеры json которые скушают js

Comment: @eri например? Никогда не слышал о таких

Comment: @Inventor вижу нашел;)

Answer (score 2):

Если известно что у вас данные в коде размещены как полностью валидный JSON, то их не сложно вытащить, т.к. для JSON есть готовые регулярные выражения.

Я оформил пример извлечения из HTML в следующем коде. Для его работы необходимо установить один `regex` PIP модуль (один раз) `python -m pip install regex`.

Суть работы моего алгоритма следующая. Берётся регулярное выражение для полной валидации JSON (его можно увидеть в коде функции `extract_jsons(...)`. Далее из HTML извлекаются все подстроки которые являются валидным JSON, кроме основного дампа данных могут быть ещё много мелких (одиночные числа, строки и т.п.). Сортируем по убыванию длины полученных подстрок, в надежде что наши данные будут самой длинной строкой. Ну и для вывода данны в консоль или сохранения куда либо мы красиво их форматируем используя `json` модуль.

Проверьте, если для вас сработает то очень здорово, если нет, значит там не валидный JSON, а просто валидный JavaScript объект (т.к. он от JSON может отличаться послаблением правил), тогда надо регулярное выражение наше дорабатывать именно под JavaScript синтаксис объектов, это не очень сложно, но нужен актуальный пример. Сообщайте о ваших результатах, если надо регулярное выражение доработаем!

[Попробовать код ниже онлайн!](https://tio.run/##3VRtb9MwEP6eX3FzJRpv6cteQCz0RYh10r4A0ooEJKFyG7fLyNscZ1rp9tvH2U63tmNoCPgA/pD4znfPne/ucT6XZ1m6f3sb8inwKynYRI7OiywtbIkidS3AFSV5JiQIPuNXwArcaLWyGwkOXVQ0J1mSRzG3BSFEnwLYfftocHzydkArhdZ10jIZc9FDodFHuQvebuMwuG7b/S0/pEDBD3fA9pv4o2jg8UEA3k4j6IPRUIWzhjjOspizVEFKUXK4himLC/VPyziG9fCFFFE6U7ZAEP0L8XEF22isNuBpeTxNhfRbwVJbgtduHLLGNFgc3ADdRtd1VCYEm2tQ8D2lcdXnmSoRNaKzIiMA4E3AL7bBDzagchYJg6TP0cukTLXorsKs@WXjcz6R2tNf3Keg4FZTqOS1FG42oBR@7y6@Dmm6RrEgKFQFr6RlelrQhaj2JiPdUgRahrgLdXcRrcC5cdQgnaIv/k7M76OxFlyWIgUvac5EVuZ2m8I0E5BAlCqraZSGkeTCrkbSAT29gfa1NmZ7fP7E4R6f/3vTHYU8ldE00imYmf32uvF5FOxs0uBitMKEumJCfYMJ9Scxof44v8zouL9Ds@WILbOl9I8Rz@k/kX/u/Yxf4/a@xPTvUXKZ3P/ETM2nNWrqWa9VC4aD0yHUVpdlVexU2Rgyn8kkRk4qHna2jt69GX56PwCl7FkdfRazdNYlPCVKwVnY036dhEsGkzMmCi675MPwuPGSVEcykjHvHWWTMsHOdlpGtjot444EDOeVaRhdwiRmRdElkyyVaE56nRZqe5YxKCYiymXv7nYxlxAyDN2FBWHEhd29fQfImLj3ba2Wt@toRjuw32w74C0eWKj1lc9dqF@yuOR154cW9Qu0qetIzYPnL5zHYEZ7LhAE2iMPTW4c/cY46sFxguDmlblda3m9TssUBWukS6/aYdVynDap3@BmWCZ5YbZxxsLCLrCNPLQ33mHlTR2rVqWEVYpZMg4ZcBdLl9qcqsm75Ng1PBtiNtRrB6jEscLio@6AUssygX8W4lfQrdvb7w)

```
def extract_jsons(text):
    import regex as re
    json_re = re.compile(r"""
      (?(DEFINE)
         (?<number>   -? (?= [1-9]|0(?!\d) ) \d+ (\.\d+)? ([eE] [+-]? \d+)? )    
         (?<boolean>   true | false | null )
         (?<string>    " ([^"\\\\]* | \\\\ ["\\\\bfnrt\/] | \\\\ u [0-9a-f]{4} )* " )
         (?<array>     \[  (?:  (?&json)  (?: , (?&json)  )*  )?  \s* \] )
         (?<pair>      \s* (?&string) \s* : (?&json)  )
         (?<object>    \{  (?:  (?&pair)  (?: , (?&pair)  )*  )?  \s* \} )
         (?<json>   \s* (?: (?&number) | (?&boolean) | (?&string) | (?&array) | (?&object) ) \s* )
      )
       (?&json) 
    """, re.S | re.I | re.X)
    return [m.group(0) for m in re.finditer(json_re, text)]
    
def extract_jsobjs(text):
    import regex as re
    jsobj_re = re.compile(r"""
      (?(DEFINE)
         (?<number>   -? (?= [1-9]|0(?!\d) ) \d+ (\.\d+)? ([eE] [+-]? \d+)? )    
         (?<boolean>   true | false | null )
         (?<identifier>  [0-9a-zA-Z_]+ )
         (?<sq_string>    ' ([^'\\\\]* | \\\\ ['\\\\bfnrt\/] | \\\\ u [0-9a-f]{4} )* ' )
         (?<string>    (?: (?:" ([^"\\\\]* | \\\\ ["\\\\bfnrt\/] | \\\\ u [0-9a-f]{4} )* ") | (?&sq_string)) )
         (?<array>     \[  (?:  (?&json)  (?: , (?&json)  )*  )?  \s* ,? \s* \] )
         (?<pair>      \s* (?:(?&string)|(?&identifier)) \s* : (?&json)  )
         (?<object>    \{  (?:  (?&pair)  (?: , (?&pair)  )*  )?  \s* ,? \s* \} )
         (?<json>   \s* (?: (?&number) | (?&boolean) | (?&string) | (?&array) | (?&object) ) \s* )
      )
       (?&json) 
    """, re.S | re.I | re.X)
    return [m.group(0) for m in re.finditer(jsobj_re, text)]
        
######## TEST #############

import json
    
html = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content"></div>

    <script>
        let data = {"a": 123, "b":
                [1, null, 3.0, [{
                    key: 'value',
                    'qkey': 123.456,
                    key_2: "val2",
                },false,true,]]};
    </script>
</body>
</html>
"""

#print(json.dumps(json.loads(sorted(extract_jsobjs(html),
#    key = lambda e: len(e), reverse = True)[0]), indent = 4))

print(sorted(extract_jsobjs(html), key = lambda e: len(e), reverse = True)[0])
```

Вывод:

```
 {"a": 123, "b":
                [1, null, 3.0, [{
                    key: 'value',
                    'qkey': 123.456,
                    key_2: "val2",
                },false,true,]]}
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что объекты js не схожи с json. Пример js объекта: `{admin: true}`. JSON выдаст ошибку и не распарсит такое. Должно быть: `{"admin": true}`

Comment: @Inventor А у вас именно такой случай? Вы проверили? Обычно сайты всё равно вставляют JSON. Т.к. в JavaScript можно вставлять как JSON, так и JavaScript вариант объекта, оба валидны. Если у вас такой случай что не чистый JSON то я доработаю моё регулярное выражение для нужной нотации, только сообщите нужно ли для ваших конкретных данных это.

Comment: Да, у меня именно такой случай, я проверил. Буду благодарен если поможете с регуляркой

Comment: @Inventor Доработал, попробуйте, для моих тестов по крайней мере код выше уже работает, для не-JSON варианта.

Comment: @Inventor Если не заработает, то нужно от вас не реальные данные ваши (которые могут быть секретными) а просто минимальный надуманный пример в котором используются все фишки не-JSON подхода - т.е. например лишняя запятая иногда перед `]` и `}`, строки иногда в одиночных `'`, имена ключей в объектах без кавычек как `{key: 'value'}`, вообщем пример схожий с вашим только на придуманных данных. Минимальный пример со всеми не-JSON фишками ваших данных.

Comment: @Inventor Получилось ли что нибудь с последним доработанным кодом и регуляркой выше? Она уже должна поддерживать JavaScript нотацию объектов.

Comment: Спасибо за ваши попытки помочь! Но я нашёл другое решение. Мне подсказал @eri в комментариях под вопросом. Оказываются существуют библиотеки, которые имеют такой функционал и умеют парсить js объекты. Я использовал demjson. Ещё мне помог этот вопрос, по сути там уже есть ответ на мой: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027589/how-to-convert-raw-javascript-object-to-python-dictionary

Comment: @Inventor Пожалуйста! Конечно проверенные популярные библиотеки будут надёжней в использовании! Тогда думаю мой код может просто кому то пригодиться просто в научных целях, чтобы для истории была регулярка JSON/JavaScript-Object.

Answer (score 2):

Моим решением стал пост на англоязычном stackoverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027589/how-to-convert-raw-javascript-object-to-python-dictionary

Я использовал сначала demjson, эта библиотека делает именно то, что мне нужно. Далее я узнал, что существует JSON5 стандарт, синтаксис которого 1 в 1 совпадает с объектами JS. Для работы с JSON5 в python есть библиотека pyjson5. Я использовал её. Теперь мой скрипт выполняется не 10.5 секунд, а 0.004 секунды